# Indo de um ponto para outro

Tags: prolog

Com os seguintes fatos,

```
x(p1,d1,c,d,e,f),
y(d1,d2,i,j,k,l),
z(d2,d3,o,p,q,r),
```

Pensado neles como pontos, gostaria de saber como posso ir de x a z , fazendo o input de p1 e d3.

Tenho, por exemplo:

```
write('Partida: '),nl,
read(Partida_it),
write('Destino: '),nl,
read(Destino_it),
    viagem(Partida_it,Destino_it,C,D,E,F),nl,
    write(Partida_it),write('<-->'),write(Destino_it),nl,
write('Tipo: '),write(C),nl,
write('Hora de partida: '),write(D),nl,
write('Hora de chegada: '),write(E),nl,
write('Preco: '),write(F),nl,
    fail,
```

Para o caso de ja existir essa viagem^

```
viagem(Partida_it,B,C,D,_,P1),nl,
viagem(B,Destino_it,F,_,E,P2),nl,
P is P1+P2,
write(Partida_it),write('<-->'),write(Destino_it),nl,
write('Tipo: '),write(C),write('e'),write(F),nl,
write('Hora de partida: '),write(D),nl,
write('Hora de chegada: '),write(E),nl,
write('Preco: '),write(P),nl,
    fail.
```

Estou já há umas horas preso neste problema.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Você poderia fornecer mais detalhes da sua dúvida? Que tipo de problema você está tentando resolver? Onde você travou?

Comment: Olá, obrigado!
Trata-se de uma plataforma de viagens entre varios transportes, tenho várias viagens na base de dados, por exemplo
     viagem(roma,lisboa,aviao,12:00,15:00,300).
     viagem(lisboa,porto,comboio,16:00,18:00,10).
Dando input 
write('Partida: '),nl,
read(Partida_it),
write('Destino: '),nl,
read(Destino_it).
Quero que o programa de um output das viagens necessarias para chegar de Roma ao Porto e a soma dos preços

Answer (score 4):

A sua lógica, em alto nível, seria o seguinte:

1. Se existe um viagem de `Partida` a `Destino`, faça ela e pronto;
2. Caso contrário, viaje para um ponto `X` **que você ainda não visitou**, e depois tente viajar de `X` para `Destino`.

Verificar se você já visitou `X` ou não é importante, caso contrário você pode entrar num loop infinito. Isso pode ser feito salvando os pontos por onde você já passou em uma lista, e ao escolher um destino verificando se esse ponto está ou não na lista.

Em código:

```
viajar(A, B, _, [viagem(A, B, C, D, E, F)]) :-
    viagem(A, B, C, D, E, F), % Se existe uma viagem direta de A a B
    !.                        % Não precisa procurar mais

viajar(A, B, JaVisitou, [viagem(A, X, C, D, E, F)|Lista]) :-
    viagem(A, X, C, D, E, F),           % Escolhe um destino qualquer
    \+ member(X, JaVisitou),            % Que você ainda não visitou
    viajar(X, B, [X|JaVisitou], Lista). % E tente ir dele até B
```

O resultado de uma chamada passando `Partida` e `Destino` seria uma lista de todas as viagens que têm que ser realizadas:

```
?- viajar(roma, porto, [roma], Lista).
Lista = [viagem(roma, lisboa, aviao, 12:00, 15:00, 300), viagem(lisboa, porto, comboio, 16:00, 18:00, 10)]
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/iGDsEE). A partir daí você pode fazer operações nessa lista, tipo imprimir todos os passos:

```
passos([]).
passos([viagem(A,B,C,D,E,F)|R]) :-
    write(A),write('<-->'),write(B),nl,
    write('Tipo: '),write(C),nl,
    write('Hora de partida: '),write(D),nl,
    write('Hora de chegada: '),write(E),nl,
    write('Preco: '),write(F),nl,
    passo(R).
```

E calcular o preço total:

```
preco([], 0).
preco([viagem(_,_,_,_,_,P)|R], Total) :-
    preco(R, X),
    Total is P + X.
```

Etc. Nota: nos exemplos acima, não usei recursão de cauda, para tornar a resposta mais simples e a lógica bem evidente. Na prática, você deve usar acumuladores em vez de fazer operações adicionais após a chamada recursiva.

Comment: Isso clarificou tudo! Muito obrigado!